# Ultimate Guide for Retrieving ALL Photos and Videos on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've taken on a project to retrieve as many photos from a given Android device (using Cordova) and make them available to my application.

I'm using the following code with a few variations to find the most logical places for photos to reside:

```
var path = "sdcard/DCIM/Camera";

    function gotDir(directory) {
        var directoryReader = directory.createReader();
        directoryReader.readEntries(function (entries) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                console.log(entries[i].name);
            }
        });
    };

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory(path, {}, gotDir, function(e){console.log(e)})
    }

    window.requestFileSystem(0-9, 0, gotFS, function(e){console.log(e)})
```

Where most examples use LocalFileSystem.Persistent in place of where I have "0-9", I noticed that that just returns an int, so I started running this same code only changing the number to see what the root level paths were available in the entries object.

I discovered that 6 and 9 were the most promising on Android, with caveats and many variables.
On my Note 4, photos were available on FileSystem(9,...) for both internal and SD external storage at:
storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera and storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera

However running this in different simulators, the default simulator didn't have a FileSystem(9,...), only 6, and the Nexus 5 simulator had a FileSystem(9,...) but the path was DCIM/and100.

It'd be great if someone could help this post by providing a definitive solution to retrieving a list of all photos on Android, regardless of device or manufacturer.